# Get original value of select option

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a button on a page to have users revert an input field option to what the original value was

```
val = inputfield.text()
if (!val){
    val = $(inputfield).attr("value")
}
inputfield.val(val)
```

This works for all input fields except select dropdowns.

If I have a dropdown with the values '1', '2', '3' and I have '2' initially selected, and then change the selected option to be '1'. `inputfield.find(':selected')` will return '1' but is there any way to have it return the initial value ('2' in this case).

Checking the source of the page will still show '2' as selected.

Comment: Are the inputs in a form?  If so, `form.reset()` will reset the inputs back to what they were on page load. Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: I do not want to reset the entire form, just the individual field

Answer (score 1):

One simplified option could be to store the original value of the dropdown on page load, say, in local Storage or something innocuous like that.

You could then use something like the following to 'reset' your dropdown as needed:

Given your parameters:

```
<div>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
</div>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

You could possibly use something like this:

```
var org = $('div select').find(':selected').text()

$('#reset').on('click',function(){
  $('div select').val(org)
})
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the [defaultSelected](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_defaultselected.asp) property.

`.prop('defaultSelected')` will only return true for the original select option

Here is how I modified my code to reset the select option back to its original value:

```
inputfield.find('option').prop('selected', function () {
    if($(this).prop('defaultSelected')){
        val = $(this).val();
        inputfield.val(val);
    }
});
```